Sentry Userfeedback always shows incorrect environment
On the new User Feedback menu of the sentry dashboard, it always shows the production environment. But I set TEST_ENV using Browser JS.
Sentry.init({
dsn: dsn,
integrations: [
    Sentry.replayIntegration({
        maskAllText: false,
        maskAllInputs: false,
        blockAllMedia: false,
        unblock: [".unblock-me"],
        unmask: [".unmask-me"]
    })
],
replaysSessionSampleRate: 1.0,
replaysOnErrorSampleRate: 1.0,
environment: "TEST_ENV" });

Image here
But if I switch to Old User Feedback from the top right button, I find the correct feedback using Filter Environment.
Old View mage here
[Note: Always shows the correct environment in Link Error (event). I am using Blazor and I tried SentrySdk from Sentry.AspNetCore nuget]
